Google app script form submit trigger throws a message This trigger has been disabled for an unknown reason
I am creating a google form add on , and i created a trigger on form submit , but for some reason it says "This trigger has been disabled for an unknown reason."
I tried using app script sample provided on https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/main/forms but its throwing the same error , so it has to be something with google cloud project.
It was working few days back .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
